# Override exported variable in file within __mocks__ folder in jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a `__mocks__` folder with a file called `example.ts` in it

**File Content (shortened for simplicity)**

```
export let token: string | null = "exampleString";
```

I have a test file where I use this variable in all the test cases.

There is one in particular where I want to override the value of this variable to be null

Approaches tried:

1. Use a proxy to try to intercept the variable when the function to be tested is called (no success, variable still set to `exampleString`
2. Use jest.spyOn to try and override the variable, still no success
3. Used `jest.unmock('../../modules/__mocks__/example');` to try and use the real implementation of the file but no success

Has anyone got an idea on how to successfully override the value of the variable for a single test case?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could shadow the typical mock by declaring a variable in the test's scope.

For example:

```
// __mocks__/example.ts

export const token = 'exampleString';
```

```
// __tests__/foo.spec.ts

import { token } from '../__mocks__/example.ts';
import a from '../foo.ts';

describe('foo', () => {
  it('does something', () => {
    const actual = foo.doSomething(token);
    /* ... */
  });

  it('does something else', () => {
    const token = null;
    const actual = foo.doSomethingElse(token);
    /* ... */
  });
});
```

Comment: Interesting concept of shadowing, wasn't aware of it, in my scenario though and my question may have induced this answer so apologies, the token variable is consumed directly from the function I am testing, i.e. I don't pass it as an argument. It gets imported to the file the function lives on

Comment: If the token isn't a parameter to the function your testing, when would it change? If it's constant throughout the life of your application, there's no need to test the case where it's null.

Comment: token might be `string | null` and I want to test both scenarios

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Could you please upload some sample code that references the token and some code that would cause it to change?

Comment: I get the token from a meta tag in the window. If it is there it is a string, if it isn't, it becomes null. There are only those two scenarios

Comment: You shouldn't import files from `__mocks__`, that's an anti-pattern. When you put the `__mocks__` folder at the right place, you should be able to just call `jest.mock('./path/to/module')`. See https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules

Comment: I'm not importing files from `__mocks__` and doing `jest.mock()` when I have a manual `__mocks__` folder will ignore the .mock call as the manual mock takes precedence